# What do the letters below each class mean?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

On the class selection screen there are four small colored letters shown below each class. What do these letters mean?

[image: Class selection screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The letters are rankings for the class's offense, defense, healing, and difficulty of player control respectively. You can view them in more detail with ZR (Display Class Info). This screen also says the current class rank and how quickly the character will rank up with this class in the top right.

[image: class info screen]

This is explained in the tip "Fostering Classes"

[image: tutorial text for class ranks]